# AngularJS and Youtube, call a script when video finishes playing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, youtube

I am trying to call a function when youtube finishes playing a video.
I have set up a view like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">

        <div id="player" ts-video-player></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

then I decided to set up a directive like this:

```
.directive('tsVideoPlayer', ['$state', function ($state) {


    // autoplay video
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
        console.log('autoplay');

        event.target.playVideo();
    }

    // when video ends
    function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data === 0) {
            console.log('finsihed');

            alert('done');
        }
    }

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {

            console.log('set up player');
            console.log(element.attr('id'));

            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {

                console.log('Creating player');

                var player = new YT.Player(element.attr('id'), {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'GE2BkLqMef4',
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

I have included this script in the index.html file:

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

But nothing happens.
My console logs show the 'setting up video player' and the player id, but the **onYouTubePlayerAPIReady** never gets called.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Where are you calling `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()` ?

Comment: nowhere, apparently this function is called when the youtube api has loaded.

Comment: I inspected youtube's script code and it has a reference to that function but it should only run if it is defined in the window object, which doesn't happen when you create a function inside a directive's scope. Try calling the function after it's definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason could be because the function you have defined is inside a directive linking function closure. YouTube api cannot access that method. You would need to put it the window object. You could in couple of ways:

**1) Create a global function and notify via eventing**

Just before end of your body tag put place the function on the global scope and get hold of the angular rootScope element and broadcast an event:

```
<script>
  function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(){
    angular.element(document).ready(function(){
       var rootScope = angular.element(document).injector().get('$rootScope');
       rootScope.$broadcast('onYouTubePlayerAPIReady');
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>
```

and subscribe to this event in your directive.

```
.directive('tsVideoPlayer', [function () {


    // autoplay video
    //....

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
           //....
            scope.$on('onYouTubePlayerAPIReady', function() {
              console.log('Creating player');
               var player = new YT.Player(element.attr('id'), {
                  .....
                });
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/riQKfe?p=info)**

---

**2) Check for Status in the directive itself**

Another way is check for `YT` object and its `loaded` status and do necessary actions.

```
.directive('tsVideoPlayer', ['$window', function ($window) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            console.log(YT.loaded);

            if (!YT) {
                console.log('playerNotLoaded');
                $window.onYouTubePlayerAPIReady = onPlayerRady;
            } else if (YT.loaded) {
                onPlayerRady();
            } else {
                YT.ready(onPlayerRady);
            }

            function onPlayerRady() {
                console.log('Creating player');
                var player = new YT.Player(element.attr('id'), {
                    height: '390',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'GE2BkLqMef4',
                    events: {
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                });
            }

            console.log(YT.loaded);
            // autoplay video
            function onPlayerReady(event) {
                console.log('autoplay');

                event.target.playVideo();
            }

            // when video ends
            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data === 0) {
                    console.log('finsihed');

                    alert('done');
                }
            }

        }
    }
}]);
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3hUR3z?p=preview)**

Comment: @Gino Yeah i have not tested it in IE5.